# Timestamps in upstart logs

Tags: logging, upstart

I'm using upstart on Ubuntu to manage services.  It writes to `/var/log/upstart/<service>.log`.  Errors in this file don't have timestamps, which makes it difficult to diagnose problems.

Is there a way -- a stanza of some kind in the config file -- to tell upstart to write timestamps with its log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a much more elegant way to do what you want, but I've found the following ghetto method to be sufficiently effective :

```
           echo "`date` : Doing the next thing..."
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`annotate-output`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/annotate-output.1.html) shell script from the [devscripts](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/devscripts) package:

Source code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/devscripts/trusty/view/head:/scripts/annotate-output.sh).

Answer (score -1):

Your service should maintain the dates/timing... 
The logs which appear in the logs under `/var/log/upstart/` are the output of your upstart script .

Also you can add a pre-start and a pre-stop section into your conf file, to print the time before the service is ran and the timing after the service has stopped:

```
pre-start script
    echo "[`date`] <YOUR SERVICE NAME> Starting" >> /var/log/<YOUR SERVICE NAME>.log
end script

pre-stop script
    echo "[`date`] <YOUR SERVICE NAME> Stopping" >> /var/log/<YOUR SERVICE NAME>.log
end script
```